# Configure 3rd-party apps using MDM or Apple Configurator on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

I am using MDM to configure e-mail accounts on iOS devices using Mail/Exchange ActiveSync payload. Is there a way to configure 3rd-party iOS apps like OneDrive and DropBox using MDM or Apple Configurator?

I am aware that using MDM, an iOS device can be configured to come pre-installed with 3rd-party apps, but is there a way where the apps themselves can be configured too, like logging into one with a specific account?

Comment: Dropbox for one doesn't support this kind of functionality: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Revisited-Managed-App-Settings-using-MDM-software-Keys-for-auto/td-p/259006

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks for your input! appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the [Managed Apps & Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/ManagedAppsUpdates/ManagedAppsUpdates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH10-SW1) section in Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference guide.

> an MDM server can provide configuration dictionaries to managed apps and can read response dictionaries from those apps. Apps can take advantage of this functionality to preconfigure themselves in a supervised environment, such as a classroom setting.

Go through the linked web-page. It is apparent that while it is possible to leverage MDM to configure an app but it will require support from the 3rd party app developer. An enterprise app created by the same company managing the device can program their app to be configured this way. Support for 3rd party app like Dropbox and OneDrive depends on how it was programmed by their development team.

It's recommended to get in touch with developer in app specific manner where this feature is required.

Comment: That answers it all ! Thanks again for all the help !